# Tkinter .set() and *

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created an array of multiple items

```
textdisplay = ["abc\n", "def\n", "ghi\n"]
```

and when I print the array normally, as `print(textdisplay)`, I get this:

```
["abc\n", "def\n", "ghi\n"]
```

and when I print the same array but with `print(*textdisplay)`, I get this:

```rb
abc
def
ghi
```

Now, I am using the .set function in tkinter for labels:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

arraystr = StringVar()
arraystr.set(*textdisplay)

label = Label(root, textvariable=arraystr)
label.pack()
```

But I get an error telling me I cannot use `*` in .set.

```
TypeError: set() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

How else can I have the array displayed via .set without the brackets and \n?

Comment: Please paste the full traceback so that we can see the exact error.

Comment: `print(*textdisplay)` is equivalent (in this particular case) to `print(textdisplay[0], textdisplay[1], textdisplay[2])` - the effect of the `*` is to split a sequence into individual parameters.  This works in the case of `print()`, which takes an arbitrary number of parameters.  `.set()`, however, only takes a single parameter - you'd have to join everything into a single string yourself.  Try `arraystr.set("\n".join(textdisplay))`, perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
# Turn array into newline-delimited string
arr_as_string = '\n'.join(text_display)
arraystr.set(arr_as_string)
```

Comment: Great Idea! It works, but I would remove the `\n` as it is already in the array. Thanks!